# Does Realm deleteAll() Reset Primary Keys

Tags: ios, swift, realm

If I have a Realm class with a primary key like this:

```
class Thing: Object{
  @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
  }
}
```

And I fill up my Realm with a bunch of data, including a `Thing` record with an `id` of `abcdef123`.

And then if I delete it all like this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
realm.beginWrite()
realm.deleteAll()
try! realm.commitWrite()
```

Will the primary key `abcdef123` still be unusable? Or does the `deleteAll()` clear out all primary keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Realm.deleteAll()` removes all objects stored in the Realm. The values of primary key properties must be *unique amongst objects stored in the Realm*. Deleting an object with a given primary key value allows that value to be used for a new object going forwards.